# Laravel not validate html select box

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have problem with validating html select. I put rules and all other form controls work fine but only select not show validate message.

**Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'post';

   
static $rules = [
'title' => 'required',
    'slug' => 'required',
'user_id' => 'required|not_in:0',
    'meta_title' => 'required',
    'meta_description' => 'required',
'post_category_id' => 'required'
];
}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('post_category_id', 'Category') }}
    <select name="post_category_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select Category</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $post->post_category_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select> {!! $errors->first('post_category_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate(Post::$rules);

        $post = Post::create($request->all());

        Alert::alert('Success', 'Post created successfully.', 'Type');

        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
    }
```

What i do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the option has the value 0 it is still present so, no error will be triggered for "required" rule

Use a disabled option instead

```
<select name="post_category_id" class="form-control">
    <option disabled>Select a Category</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $post->post_category_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: This will work only if i add selected after disabled. When i submit form validation work but no message showed like on another input textboxes. All validation error messages was showed even on select not showed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you have a default value set on your placeholder of the select, so the input will always be valid since its always sent to the backend.
take a look at this line : Select Category
you're setting a default value, remove it and try again:

in your blade do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('post_category_id', 'Category') }}
    <select name="post_category_id" class="form-control">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $post->post_category_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select> {!! $errors->first('post_category_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>
```